# Запятая в выражении "таким, как"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Сначала ребёнка надо научить выражениям — таким(,) как "Моя Родина - Россия"* и т. п.

Нужна ли запятая в скобках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-разному бывает, но Вы же контекст не дали... Держите общее правило.

[**ТАКОЙ (,) КАК**, *местоимение + союз*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722)

> По общему правилу, обороты с союзом «как» выделяются запятыми, если в
>   основной части предложения имеется указательное слово «такой».
>
> *Он, рыжий человечек, может назвать **такие** имена, **как** Малянов Дмитрий Алексеевич, астроном, Губарь Захар Захарович, инженер, и
>   Снеговой Арнольд Павлович, химико-физик.* А. и Б. Стругацкие, За
>   миллиард лет до конца света. *Быть может, только **такие** люди,
>   **как** Шиллер, могли быть достойны ее любви.* К. Паустовский, Ручьи, где плещется форель. *Отчего же ты не старый, // А **такой, как** был
>   тогда?* А. Ахматова, Веет ветер лебединый... *«…Это в общем сон, но не
>   **такой, как** обычно»*... Б. Окуджава, Путешествие дилетантов. *Садись **такой, как** ты есть. Не принаряжайся.* Б. Пастернак, Доктор Живаго. *Дуб был точно **такой, как** в царскосельском саду.* Ю.
>   Тынянов. Кюхля. ***Такие, как*** ты, рождались во все эпохи кровавой
>   истории наших планет. А. и Б. Стругацкие, Трудно быть богом. *Теперь,
>   хлопче, скажу тебе, и бабы не **такие, как** прежде.* В. Короленко,
>   Лес шумит.

***Однако в некоторых случаях запятая ставится не перед словом «как», а перед словом «такой»:***

> 1) если слова «такой как» соотносятся с предшествующим прилагательным:
>   *Погода дождливая, **такая как** осенью. Обстановка в этом доме была мрачная, **такая как** в старинных замках* (ср.: *Погода **такая,
>   как** осенью. Обстановка в этом доме была **такая, как** в старинных
>   замках*);
>
> 2) если слова «такие как» употребляются после обобщающего слова перед
>   рядом однородных членов (после слов «такие как» двоеточие не
>   требуется): *Туристы посетили старинные города, **такие как** Суздаль,
>   Владимир, Ростов Великий.*

Comment: Правила я уже читал, но не смог применить.  
А какого размера нужен контекст? Ведь в примерах его тоже нет, а правила работают.

Comment: Возьму на себя смелость тако просуммировать вышесказанное:
запятая ставится перед "такой" при условии, что смысл предложения не изменится при мысленной замене "такой как" на "как". В остальных случаях "такой" и "как" разделяются запятой.
Правильно?

Comment: Ой нет,  Michael не о том. Увидела, чуть подправив вопрос, что контекста достаточно. У нас явно не то, что оговорено в двух пунктах ***Однако в некоторых случаях запятая ставится не перед словом «как», а перед словом «такой»***, значит, автоматически ставим: ***таким, как "Моя Родина - Россия"***, но - что-то меня предшествующее тире смущает.

Comment: Один специалист сказал, что должно быть так:
Сначала ребёнка надо научить выражениям, таким как: "моя Родина - Россия", "выражение2", "выражение3". То есть выражения в кавычках с мал. буквы.
Как по-вашему, насколько это верно?

Comment: Если в кавычках полновесное предложение, то с прописной: ***...таким, как "Мама мыла раму", "Мы не рабы, рабы не мы", "Поздравляю вас, гражданин, соврамши".*** Если перечень предложений-выражений содержит более трёх примеров, то и двоеточие перед ним напрашивается.