# «Такие как» — где ставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые

> *Но и другие англоязычные страны(,) такие, как Великобритания и Австралия, тоже придерживаются этой традиции.*

Ставится ли запятая перед словом "такие"? По какому правилу?

Comment: В заголовке: запятая **перед** словом "такие". В тексте вопроса: запятая **после** слова такие. Думаю, надо подправить. Я рассказала про обе.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запятая в выражении "таким, как"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448903/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ТАКОЙ (,) КАК](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722), *местоимение + союз*
По общему правилу, обороты с союзом «как» выделяются запятыми, если в основной части предложения имеется указательное слово «такой».
**Но!** Если слова «такие как» употребляются после обобщающего слова перед рядом однородных членов, то запятая ставится не перед словом «как», а перед словом «такие» (при этом двоеточие после слов «такие как» не требуется):
*Туристы посетили старинные города, такие как Суздаль, Владимир, Ростов Великий.*

В нашем случае одна запятая ставится перед словами «такие как», вторая — после всего уточняющего оборота.
**Но и другие англоязычные страны, такие как Великобритания и Австралия, тоже придерживаются этой традиции.**

> Там вы найдете богатые нефтью страны, такие как Саудовская Аравия и Кувейт, подушевой доход в которых близок к показателям тридцати самых богатых государств.   (Д. Робинсон, Д. Аджемоглу)

[«Такие… как» — где нужна запятая?](https://popravilam.com/blog/161-takie-kak.html)