# «Такие как» — знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, обороты-с-как

Как правильно расставить запятые в данном предложении?

Например, больным с такими генетическими заболеваниями, как Синдром Дауна, целительная сила может помочь в адаптации к жизненному процессу и облегчить психологическое состояние человека.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запятая в выражении "таким, как"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448903/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba)

Answer (score 4):

В данном предложении запятые стоят верно.

*Например, больным с **такими** генетическими заболеваниями, **как** Синдром Дауна, целительная сила может помочь...*

[**ТАКОЙ (,) КАК**, *местоимение + союз*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722)

> По общему правилу, обороты с союзом «как» выделяются запятыми, если в основной части предложения имеется указательное слово «такой».
>
> *Быть может, только **такие** люди, **как** Шиллер, могли быть достойны ее любви.* К. Паустовский, Ручьи, где плещется форель.